# Simple Tomcat Question Create a New Folder under Webapps folder

Tags: tomcat, servlets

I would like to test it by myself if I had a test server.

I need to create a new application JSP applicaiton. I created a folder, say, app1, under webapps folder. Then I made an empty file index.jsp there under app1. Then I visit http://aba.com/app1/index.jsp but get a 404 errror (not found).

Do I need to restart tomecat after app1 folder is created?

Comment: you should be able to do that without restarting.  I started to doubt myself for some reason, and just tested to be sure.

Comment: Revdrjrr, can you reply so I can select your reply your answer as solution?

Comment: Thanks David.  I added some additional info in the answer.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do that and see your changes without restarting.  However, you may also want to look into a more robust method of testing and viewing your changes.  If you're using tomcat and maven, you may want to use the tomcat maven plugin, which will give you several different deployment options so you can keep your workspace separate from your tomcat install's webapps directory.